# Problems in Using JLabel to Display a Chosen Image File

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I encountered a problem while I am trying to display an image after I clicked a button and chose image file within the "Choose File Dialog".

Initially, I was managed to display the chosen image in `JLabel`, but later I created a separate `ActionListener`, I think it started to go wrong since then. Whatever image I choose, the `JLabel` won't display it.

I debugged it, and sure that the file chooser does pass the image to `ImageIcon`, `JLabel` does get the value from `ImageIcon`, but it doesn't display the image even after `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

Here I attached my code for your kind reference!

(I trimmed the code for a clean look, so there might be some brackets left not useful)

```java
package com.xxx.LoyalCardManager;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class LoyalCardManagerMain implements ActionListener{

private JFrame frame;
private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler();


private JLabel labelPic;

private JButton buttonPic;

private File picFile = new File("");
private BufferedImage image;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws SQLException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LoyalCardManagerMain window = new LoyalCardManagerMain();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}



}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public LoyalCardManagerMain() {

    // Database initialisation
    initDatabase();

    // Draw GUI
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 619, 487);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    buttonPic = new JButton("Click to Choose Pic");
    buttonPic.setBounds(415, 252, 166, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPic);
    buttonPic.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPic.setActionCommand("ChoosePic");
    buttonPic.addActionListener(this);

    labelPic = new JLabel();
    labelPic.setBounds(415, 30, 167, 210);
    frame.getContentPane().add(labelPic);




}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String command = event.getActionCommand();

     if (command.equals("ChoosePic")) {
        //TODO Label now cannot display images.
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept (File f) {
                String extension = Utils.getExtension(f);
                if(extension != null) {
                    if (extension.equals(Utils.gif) ||
                        extension.equals(Utils.jpeg) ||
                        extension.equals(Utils.jpg) ||
                        extension.equals(Utils.png) ||
                        extension.equals(Utils.tif) ||
                        extension.equals(Utils.tiff)) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            public String getDescription() {
                return "Image File (*.gif, *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.png, *.tif, *.tiff)";
            }

        });

        int retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            picFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(picFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Calculate the pic's ratio and do re-scale

            double ratio = (double) labelPic.getWidth() / (double) labelPic.getHeight();
            // Do image scale, scaledW is the new Width, and LabelPic.getHeight is the new Height.
            int scaledW = (int) (image.getHeight() * ratio);
            image = new BufferedImage(scaledW, labelPic.getHeight(), BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

            labelPic.setVisible(true);
            labelPic.setIcon(icon);
            labelPic.revalidate();
            labelPic.repaint();

        }


    }
}
}
```

I also referenced other similar questions:

[image loading using a JFileChooser into a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737029/image-loading-using-a-jfilechooser-into-a-jframe)

[Image won't display in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883937/image-wont-display-in-jlabel)

[Updating an image contained in a JLabel - problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051638/updating-an-image-contained-in-a-jlabel-problems)

External Site: [JFIleChooser opening image to JLabel](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/253216-jfilechooser-opening-image-to-jlabel/)

As well as Java Tutorial Docs
[How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

But I still can't figure it out why the JLabel not display the chosen image.

Thanks for your kind help mates!

Comment: If it is possible try to create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that will reproduce your problem (remove db usage for example)

Comment: @Pshemo OK no problem, I'm starting to get rid  off those irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out what's wrong with the code:

If I intend to use `BufferedImage` to resize (sorry, in my question I mis-understanding the method `scale` with `resize`), I need to use `drawImage` method to "redraw" the image. Otherwise the image will not be shown.

I made modification here:

```
double ratio = (double) labelPic.getWidth() / (double) labelPic.getHeight();
        // Do image scale, scaledW is the new Width, and LabelPic.getHeight is the new Height.
        int scaledW = (int) (image.getHeight() * ratio);
        image = new BufferedImage(scaledW, labelPic.getHeight(), BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);// Edit here
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

        labelPic.setVisible(true);
        labelPic.setIcon(icon);
        labelPic.revalidate();
        labelPic.repaint();
```

From the "Edit Here" mark, I use the following code:

```
BufferedImage imageTemp = new BufferedImage(resizedW, resizedH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            imageTemp.getGraphics().drawImage(image,0,0, scaledW, scaledH, null);
            image = imageTemp;
```

And there's difference between first pass the value to `imageTemp` then pass to `image` and directly pass the value to `image`. If I pass the `new BufferedImage` directly to `image`, it will display a pure black colour instead of the image you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to display the image:

```
        JfileChooser getImage = new JFileChooser();
        ..........

        ImageIcon imagePath= new ImageIcon(getImage.getPath());

        JLabel imageLabel= new JLabel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(imagePath.getImage(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
            }
        };
        imageLabel.setLocation(10, 40);
        imageLabel.setBorder(viewAnimalPanelBorder);
        imageLabel.setSize(200, newHeight);
        panel.add(imageLabel);
```

Let me know if you require more assistance.

Also, try displaying the picture without using the JFileChooser, maybe hard code the path for a test.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still can't display.

Comment: Does the image show if you hardcode or select a image, bypassing the jfilechooser?

Comment: Ok, you try rounding the height to a int, and for validation, print the height and width to the screen to see that it is > 0. In the mean while, I will get my scale model ready then you can try it.

Comment: @theoron thanks for your help, but I've managed to solve it myself!

Comment: Pleasure, what was the problem, or the solution?